# Symfony : Authenticate user in functional test

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to authenticate a User in a functional test, to check if he is redirected.

My controller :

```
public function preRegisterAction()
{
    if ($this->getUser() instanceof User) {
        return new RedirectResponse();
    }

    return $this->render(
        'pages/pre-register.html.twig'
    );
}
```

My test :

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient();
}

public function testPreRegisterAction()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setEmail('test@test.fr');
    $user->setCreated(new \DateTime());
    $user->setId(43);

    $tokenStorage = $this->client->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage');
    $tokenStorage->setToken(new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', ['ROLE_USER']));

    $this->client->request('GET', '/choix');
    $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isRedirection());
}
```

I don't know if the use of assertion is okay. But even the use of token storage doesn't seem to work. When I do a var_dump of tokenstorage in my controller, I don't see the User which I injected in the test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why your code doesn't work in tests. I don't have a deep knowledge of security component, but there are two recommended ways to authenticate user.

1. [Using a Faster Authentication Mechanism Only for Tests](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html#using-a-faster-authentication-mechanism-only-for-tests)
2. [Creating the Authentication Token](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html#creating-the-authentication-token)